# SEO Keyword Research Help

Tags: seo, keywords

I'm new at SEO and keyword research. I am using Market Samurai as my research tool, and I was wondering if I could ask for your help to identify the best key word to target for my niche. I do plan on incorporating all of them into my site, but I wanted to start with one. If you could give me your input on these keywords, I would appreciate it. This is all new to me :)

I'm too new to post pictures, but here are my keywords (Searches, SEO Traffic, and SEO Value / Day):

```
Searches | SEO Traffic  |  PBR  | SEO Value | Average PR/Backlinks of Current Top 10   

1: 730   | 307          |  20%   | 2311.33   | 1.9 / 7k-60k
2: 325   | 137          |  24%   | 822.94    | 2.3 / 7k-60k
3: 398   | 167          |  82%   | 589.79    | 1.6 / 7k-60k
```

I'm wondering if the PBR (Phrase-to-broad) value of #1 is too low. It seems like the best value because the SEOV is crazy high. That is like $70k a month. #3 has the highest PBR, but also the lowest SEOV. #2 doesn't seem worth it because of the PR competetion. Might be a little too hard to get into the top page of Google.

I'm wondering which keywords to target, and if I should be looking at any other metric to see if this is a profitable niche to jump into.

Thanks.

Comment: Wow, whatever tool creates that chart really takes the cake for making up metrics.

Comment: PBR is 4.74% – 5.9% according to wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

SEOT is the amount of search engine traffic that a site in the number 1 position in Google could expect for a chosen period. Anything above 150 in SEOT is fine for me and higher the better. (Here I am assuming in Market Samurai your match type is "Exact" and Period is "Daily")
SEOV of 2300+ is a very good value to target but make sure to check the competition -SEOC- as well. Such high value keywords normally have lots of competition.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably attempt to go after the first one. It has the highest SEO Traffic. I wouldn't worry about the low PBR. It's low, but I consider too low to be under 15%.

Another metric to look at is the SEO competition. This is kind of shown by the pageranks, but I know Market Samurai will give you a number for this. I usually look at the ratio of SEO Traffic to SEO Competition to choose which keyword to target first.